# Docker+WSL2+.Net Core Assign constant port that works with localhost

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, wsl-2

I have let Visual Studio 2019 create the standard GRPC .Net Core template program as a starting point. I have also ticked the option to let the GRPC service run inside a Docker (Linux/WSL2) container.

My problem is, that the port under which I can reach the docker image, is constantly changing and I cannot find a way to assign a static one.

[image]

If I use https://localhost:32776, I can reach the service insider the Docker container. However, the port portion is changing with each restart of the container. Is there a way to always use the same port, e.g. 5001?

That's my Dockerfile as automatically created by Visual Studio:
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj", "GrpcService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GrpcService/GrpcService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GrpcService"
RUN dotnet build "GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GrpcService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrpcService.dll"]
```

And this is launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "GrpcService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code, rather than image.

Comment: I have replaced them.